# Doch vs. noch/gar?

Tags: grammar, negation, modal-particle

> Und viele mancher Kollegen wüssten doch noch gar nicht, dass sie nicht
>   wieder kommen würden.[<sup>[FAZ]</sup>](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/bundestag-immer-schoen-reziplikativ-bleiben-12262592.html)

1. How can *doch noch gar* be translated, when, according to my dictionary, both *doch* and *noch* can be translated as *still*?
2. Do we have here a case of reported speech?

Comment: are you sure your example sentence is correct? i stumble upon "viele mancher" which means "many of some"...

Comment: I don't know. But you can read it where I found it a few days ago. Just check out the link above.

Comment: looks like they really wrote this

Comment: @Vogel612 Wrote it, yes, but did not mean it! Obviously a slip of the keyboard. Switch out _mancher_ for _ihrer_ and it makes perfect sense again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: “Viele mancher Kollegen” is almost certainly wrong, as already noted by Vogel612 and Eugene Seidel. Perhaps it read originally “Mancher Kollege wisse …” and was redacted incompletely later; or it should be “Viele ihrer Kollegen …”, as proposed by Eugene. I’ll assume Eugene’s version here. – Also, “wieder kommen” should read “wiederkommen”.

Now, to your questions:

- Yes, it is reported speech that is continued from the previous sentence:

  > Sie wisse von nichts, sagt Ulrike Flach von der FDP, eine der dazu Einzuladenden. Und viele [ihrer] Kollegen wüssten doch noch gar nicht, dass sie nicht [wiederkommen] würden.

  So everything is an indirect quote by this *Ulrike Flach von der FDP, eine der dazu Einzuladenden*. In direct speech, it would read something like this:

  > Ich weiß von nichts. Viele meiner Kollegen wissen doch noch gar nicht, daß sie nicht wiederkommen werden.
- Regarding the “doch noch gar nicht”, *doch* and *noch gar nicht* are two different parts.

  *Noch nicht* means *not yet*. The negation is modified by *gar* (here equivalent to *even*): *They don’t even know yet …*

  For the meaning of *doch*, let’s first have a look at the context: It’s the last day the parliament is in session before election day. Some members (Ulrike Flach among them) aren’t running again, so it’s certain they won’t be members anymore when the parliament reconvenes; others may be re-elected or not, only time will tell. There are rumours that the president has arranged some kind of farewell ceremony for those leaving, but Flach refutes these claims: One, she hasn’t received an invitation, even though she will be leaving for certain; two, nobody can know who should be invited to this purported ceremony.

  The modal particle *doch* here has the function to mark the argument as logical and unsurprising to the recipient. If I had to translate it, I’d therefore try with *obviously*:

  > Obviously, many of my fellow members don’t even know yet that they won’t be returning.

Comment: simply use `return` instead of `be returning` in your suggested translation since the speaker don't speak about the process of the returning. Present Progressive doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Many thanks, indeed. Unexpectedly detailed (for which I'm perfectly happy, of course!). I apologize for not yet being able to answer in German.

Comment: In this particular sentence I'd translate *gar* to *at all*, not *even*. It's synonymous to *überhaupt*, not to *sogar*. So, "They don't know yet at all that...". Also see [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gar#Adverb)

Answer (score 1):

Let us dissect this wonderful example of written German language:

#### Indirect/reported speech

Yes, your guess is right this is an example of using subjunctive (*"wüssten"*) in reported speech.

**doch**

In this case *"doch"* is used as a modal particle to gently shift the meaning of the surrounding sentence. Here it may be intended to achieve some empathy or even agreement for the fact that the people we are talking about do not yet know (*"wissen"*). I can't think of an English counterpart to this, it may be something along the line of *"however"*, or using *"could"* instead of *"did"*.

#### noch

This adverb is a often used for a temporal restriction of the following negation.

> *They do not **yet** know (but they might know in the future)*.

#### gar

Another adverb often used to emphasis a negation.

> *They do not know **at all***.

#### viele mancher

Thats unsual indeed. It seems like an antagonims but it may be intended in this case where the author possibly wanted to express in few words that it were many of a smaller group of people, like saying *many of the few*.

Comment: Yes, the emperor's clothes are splendid LOL

Comment: @EugeneSeidel damn right they are

Comment: @Emanuel: it may be the same issue than ever: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site. Sadly we can do nothing about this :/

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) we will start with the basic construction to it:

> Und viele Kollegen wüssten noch nicht, dass sie nicht wiederkommen würden.

translation:
`wüssten` subjunctive of `wissen` --> know
`noch` restrictive time-adverb --> yet
`wiederkommen würden` subjunctive of `wiederkommen` --> return / come back
`Kollegen` might be best off translated as `fellow party members`
`viele mancher` @takkat translated `many of the few` (this quote comes from the now weakest "conventional" party in German Bundestag, that might fall out next legislature, the FDP (`free democratic party`), so it might be the best possible translation)

translation basic result:

> and many of the few fellow members wouldn't know yet that they would not return

**doch** and **gar** in this case act as stamination to the not-knowing of these members.
the only way i know of to reflect this in english is: `at all`, but as this conflicts with the current sentence structure (I have no idea where to place it) I thus leave it out.

ad 2) correct. the subjunctive indicates reported speech

Comment: Pretzel logic...

Comment: @EugeneSeidel wtf? where does [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_Logic) fit in?

Comment: "pretzel logic" is a figure of speech meaning "convoluted logic", Steely Dan merely appropriated it for the title of an album :)